# Trying to mute the music on tap of (speaker)image for the first time and play it for second time

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Hi i'm trying to mute the music on tap of(speaker image) for the first time and play it for second time means if it is mute it will become active and if it is active it will become mute.For refrence if we tap"volBtn" the mediaElement2 will stop and if tap it again it will play again.Any help would be appreciated.

Xaml

```
<Image x:Name="volBtn"
                Source="Assets/LearnColor/Button/btn_sound.png"              
                Height="95" Width="95"
                RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                Margin="67,0,-17,-5" d:LayoutOverrides="TopMargin,  BottomMargin,TopPosition, BottomPosition"
Tapped="volBtn_Tapped"/>
        <StackPanel>
           <MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement1" MediaEnded="eventhandler" />            
         </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel>
                <MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement2" />
                </StackPanel>
                <MediaElement x:Name="mycontrol" Source="/Audio/bg_sound.mp3"   AutoPlay="True"/>
```

C# code

```
private void volBtn_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (mediaElement2.Play)
    {

    }
    mycontrol.Stop();                
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muting is different than starting/stopping.  There is an [IsMuted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.ismuted.aspx) property that can be used if you truly are looking to mute the volume.

Then, your tapped event should be able to look something like:

```
private void volBtn_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mediaElement2.IsMuted = !mediaElement2.IsMuted;              
}
```

However, there are many other ways to do this without using the tap event of an image - just style a toggle button to use your speaker image and wire it directly to the media element, for example.

[EDIT]

My tests show that it mutes perfectly fine.  I have a feeling that I'm not understanding what you're trying to accomplish.  Working example of IsMuted below:

```
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="muteButton" OnContent="Sound Muted" OffContent="Sound On" />
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement2" AutoPlay="True"  IsMuted="{Binding ElementName=muteButton, Path=IsOn, Mode=OneWay}"
              IsLooping="True" Source="ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Default" />
```

Comment: I tried but it won't work . yes the volume can also be complete stopped

Comment: The muting does work.  You can check my example.  I'm not sure what you mean by won't work... did you get an exception?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to Play/Pause the media when user taps on the volBtn, Use `MediaElementState`. See below code.

```
private void volBtn_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    switch(mediaElement2.CurrentState)
    {
        case MediaElementState.Playing:
            mediaElement2.Pause();
            break;
        case MediaElementState.Paused:
            mediaElement2.Play();
            break;
    }
}
```

If you do not want to pause/play but just want to mute audio

```
private void volBtn_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mediaElement2.IsMuted = !mediaElement2.IsMuted;              
}
```